# why is useEffect executing after each render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im having problems with my effect hook. I only want it to render once. if I pass  album.length or an empty array it returns an empty object. If the album is added as a dependency then the effect renders as an infinite loop. any help is appreciated.

```
const [album, setAlbum] = React.useState(initialState)
const {state} = React.useContext(AuthContext);


async function fetchData(){
 try{
  const res =await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/albums/all')
  const {data}= await res;
  setAlbum({...data,albums:res.data})
  console.log(album)
  }
  catch(err){
  console.log(err);
  }
}



 useEffect(() => {fetchData();}, []);


_______________________________________________________

componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/albums/all')
.then(res=>{
    let albums=res.data.map((album)=>{
      return(
        <div key={album._id}>
       //display the album
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       )
       })
this.setState({albums:albums});
```

})
}

Comment: Please do not posts links to images of text--just post text. Or images of text; just post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const res =await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/albums/all')
const {data}= await res;
setAlbum({...data,albums:res.data})
```

Can you please explain this? Why await res and why spread data and add it as albums as well?

You could write your own hook. You should also declare the function `fetchApi` within the useEffect hook, that is why it re-renders the whole time.

Let's take your code and make a custom hook

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function useAlbums() {
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          'http://localhost:5000/api/albums/all',
        );
        setAlbums(data);
        console.log(albums);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [albums]);

  return [albums, setAlbums];
}

const Component = () => {
  // use it in component
  const [albums] = useAlbums();

  return (
    <>
      {albums.map(({ _id }) => (
        <div key={_id}>{'add more content here'}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Use with

```js
const [albums, setAlbums] = useAlbums();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had a class component and was using componentdidmount which worked fine. I started refactoring the component to functional because I will need to pass state into the component. I edited the op with what i had as a lifecycle method if that helps. @

Comment: You still have to move the fetchData function declaration into the useEffect hook

Comment: @Shirley I updated my answer to reflect your updates, does this help?

Comment: Many thanks.  i've been beating my head against the wall all day.

Comment: @Shirley Happy I could help